# Realtek driver install make error while building info.o

Tags: sound, 15.10, realtek

Running Ubuntu 15.10 on HP Pavillion 17-g121wm

I checked which driver windows was using: one was a realtek the other was a amd. In windows the AMD device was disabled so I would try to install the realtek driver. I downloaded 0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8.tar.bz2 from realtek.

I ran

```
./configure --with-cards=hda-intel
```

(I also tried `./configure`)

Lastly I ran make and got the following error

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic'
...
  CC [M]  ..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/info.o
..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/info.c: In function ‘snd_info_version_read’:
..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/info.c:1065:22: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
       "Compiled on " __DATE__ " for kernel %s"
                      ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/info.o' failed
make[3]: *** [..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/info.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:403: recipe for target '..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore' failed
make[2]: *** [..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore] Error 2
Makefile:1399: recipe for target '_module_/..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/..../Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic'
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

I tried some commands I saw on a web page thinking it may help shed some light on the issue:

```
# lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1002:9840]
00:09.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:157a]
# lsmod | grep ^snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_intel          36864  2
snd_hda_codec         135168  2 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           65536  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  13 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
```